# How to hide a tab from a fanpage during development

Tags: facebook, tabs, hide, privacy

I'm wondering how to hide a Facebook tab from a published fanpage while the tab is under development, so that it only appears for page Admins?

In order to edit tabs it seems that they have to be added to the page, in order to be able to edit them. That's a problem when customizing a Facebook tab, as you don't want your fans to see your work-in-progress content until it's ready to be published.

Here I'm not referring to a custom built app, but apps like Static HTML.

Any one who has experience with this?

Comment: Just enable Sandbox mode …?

Answer (score 0):

Enable sandbox mode in the app settings.

Goto dev https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Click on the app in the left hand column.

Under setting look to see if Sandbox mode is on or off.

If you want to change the setting click "Edit Settings"

The Sandbox setting is under basic settings.

For you and the client to test the app you have to give them permissions by adding them as a tester/developer/admin of the app.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the answers. But I can't seem to put an app that I haven't custom built myself into Sandbox mode. I'm looking to hide apps built by others - like the Static HTML app.

Comment: Judging from the answers, am I right to assume this isn't possible?If it isn't I'm just curious as to how small businesses with Facebook develop their Facebook page without their fans seeing it.